# Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with: [with list of different nvidia drivers to be install mannually]

Tags: nvidia, graphics, cuda

I recently setup my laptop to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 with Windows 10 to test some GPU related techs.

1. Post installation and updates, I changed additional driver for my TU117M Nvidia card to use nvidia-driver-515 instead of X.Org X Server. [but not it is showing continue using a manually installed driver??]
2. I installed CUDA as per instructions from to install toolkit but i missed some MOK which is because of secure boot enabled on my laptop. **but blue MOK screen on reboot didn't work because of age old problem of *password not matched* :)**

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-8-local_11.8.0-520.61.05-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-8-local_11.8.0-520.61.05-1_amd64.deb
sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-8-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

3. Later I found on web that it can be fixed by calling following command which worked like charm
   `sudo mokutil --import /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der`

I installed cuda toolkit after 2 step which I hope shouldn't be problem but I can't

1. Run nvidia-smi
2. Any GPU specific code is not working.

My guess is post reboot installation because of MOK or secure boot got messed up and I can't find any specific post about how to fix.

*Please suggest some solution and thank you for your time...*

FYI: All graphic cards since 2008 are CUDA compatiable. NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1) Check here 1024 CUDA cores [link](https://www.nvidia.com/en-eu/geforce/gaming-laptops/gtx-1650/)

[additional drivers screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcawy.png)

[$nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4lGe.png)

Comment: Do you need Secure Boot? You don't unless you're dual-booting with Windows 11.